# Not sure how to use lightbox in my vue project?

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I'm currently trying to use lightbox in my project! And as you notice I using a (v-for) for the items array.
How to integrated lightbox with v-for items?

vue-image-lightbox
A simple image lightbox component for Vuejs
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-image-lightbox

```
<div class="items" v-scroll-reveal.reset>
   <md-card 
      v-for="(product,index) in products"
      :key="index"
      v-show="product.type === activeProduct">

      <md-card-media md-ratio="16:9">
        <img :src="require(`../assets/img/products/${product.img}`)"/>
      </md-card-media>

   </md-card>
</div>
```

Comment: have you read the documentation? provide a fiddle example for better help

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `img` with `<LightBox :images="images"></LightBox>`. As per the [examples](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-image-lightbox) in the npm page, the `images` variable is an object that holds multiple resolutions of the picture.

The elements should be rendered automatically afterwards.

Comment: I Don't know what i did wrong?                           <LightBox :src="require(`../assets/img/products/${product.img}`)"></LightBox>is that okay?

Comment: The `LightBox` component has no attributes called `src`. You have to use `images` instead and it should be an array of all the image(s) you want to show as a lightbox. If you give it multiple images in an array and assign it to `:images`, it will automatically generate thumbnails based on them. Otherwise, if you only provide one image in that array, it will only display one thumbnail. That is how you control how many images show up in the thumbnail list.

Comment: So, for your case, you can form a variable like `let sources = [{ thumb: require(thumbnail_image_source), src: require(original_image_source) }]` and assign it to `:images`

Comment: Thank you for your help and support i really appreciate that! right Now I used this plugin ,vue-gallery,, (Link https://github.com/RobinCK/vue-gallery) And so far everything looks fine except the styling they don't accept the CSS grid and flex! Even i try to manipulate them in chrome devtools but for some reason they don't accept any CSS style! I know however they used a framework like bulma or something! But can i change the default behavior? or maybe disabled the default style?

Comment: Otherwise you suggest me some good plugin it can be easy to manipulate and apply style (:

Comment: https://github.com/DCzajkowski/vue-pure-lightbox#simple-example see if this helps